# Allowing access to specific pages with ASP-MVC and Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, forms-authentication

Here is a simple overview of my directory layout for my views:

Project

- Page 1
- Page 2
- RSS

Issues

- Page 1
- Page 2
- RSS

I am using forms authentication to deny access to all unauthenticated users, that works fine. However, I want to be able to grant access to the RSS views to everyone (so they can subscribe via google reader and stuff)

I understand that you can grant access to pages by adding the following page to your web.config

```
  <location path="TOURPAGE.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
    <allow users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

However, how would I do this with my dynamically made URL's, such as:

```
Issues/RSS/chrisj
```

- That path maps to a controller in issues called RSS, which takes a username and spits out an RSS of thier issues...

**EDIT**

Some answers I thought had fixed it, but:

It seems that, in my case at least, you still need the authentication cookie in order to see the page. You can be logged out and view it, so long as you have the cookie.

That is no good to me, I need the page to be completely public, as it is an RSS feed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget about the <location><allow /><deny /> stuff... sounds like you need to use the [Authorize] attribute on your actions.

Check out these pages for more info:
http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-17-cs.aspx
http://www.pnpguidance.net/post/ASPNETMVCFrameworkPreview4HandleErrorAuthorizeOutputCacheActionFilterAttributes.aspx

Also, the attribute can be applied at the controller level as well, so you don't have to put it on each individual action.

Comment: hey hi, I am doing this exact thing and its working great, but my index page forces people to login and I dont want that. I have the whole class and controller methods with [allowannonymous] but its still forcing login. can you help with that?

Answer (score 4):

This was actually much simpler than I thought. Seems .net is quite clever, I tried the following:

```
  <location path="Issues/RSS">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
    <allow users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

And it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<location path="/Issues/RSS/">
<system.web>
<authorization>
<allow users="*" />
</authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

EDIT: The reason this works by the way, is because .NET is assuming that URL goes to a directory, and this location tag above says "anything in the 'Issues/RSS' directory is safe :)

Comment: This doesn't work for me as it complains that it can't end or start with a "/".  "~/Issues" works, but not "/Issues" or "~/Issues/".

Answer (score 0):

This might not be working as intended.

It seems that, in my case at least, you still need the authentication cookie in order to see the page. You can be logged out and view it, so long as you have the cookie.

That is no good to me, I need the page to be completely public, as it is an RSS feed.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Charlino that the [Authorize] tag will probably solve your problem.

If you are using a single controller action for both RSS and a page (and are just rendering a different ActionResult based on some parameter), you can check if the user is authenticated with `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`, and use that within the controller action to decide whether or not to continue & allow access.